# SQL group by query returning error: aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I have the following table:
[image]

I'm trying to group by the Id column so it returns unique rows but the following query returns this error: Column 'Results.EventId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the query I'm running:

```
Select  events.Id, Results.EventId, results.UserId, events.Name, results.Description
FROM Events
LEFT JOIN Results ON events.Id=Results.EventId
group by events.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted this to work, you would need something like this:

```
Select e.Id, max(r.EventId), max(r.UserId), e.Name, max(r.Description)
FROM Events e LEFT JOIN
     Results r
     ON e.Id = r.EventId
group by e.Id, e.Name;
```

Note that this returns only one row per `event`.  If there are multiple rows in `results` for a given event, the results are summarized.

If `events(id)` is a primary (or unique) key and you are using a database then you can use just `group by` e.Id`.

Comment: I ran this query and it's returning this error: Column 'Events.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @esty12 . . . I revised the answer.  Clearly your database is does not support the use of primary keys like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX(Results.EventId)` or include that column in the GROUP BY terms. This is a GROUP BY / functional dependence issue.

Remember, Results.EventId could be null or non-null due to the outer join behavior.

Do the same thing for the other select list items that are not functionally dependent on the GROUP BY terms.